# JPA nested collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, relational-database

I'm working on saving schedule for shop into the db.

```
public class Shop {
   @Id
   private long id;
}


public class Schedule {
   @Id
   private long id;

   @Column
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private DayOfWeek weekday;

   @Column(name="time_from")
   private Time from;

   @Column(name="time_to")
   private Time to;      

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="shop_id")
   private Shop shop;

}
```

What I want, is to have schedule available within Shop instance (one shop can have multiple `to` and `from` times, for example 09:00-13:00, 14:00-18:00), like this

```
public class Shop {
   @Id
   private long id;

   private Map<DayOfWeek, List<Schedule>> scheduleList = new HashMap<>();
}
```

but I don't know how to map that. I was looking through the JPA 2.1 wiki page (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices), but the the criteria field is ENUM, and I think that there is no reason to create an extra table with 7 rows (for each weekday). Does anyone work with such features?

EDIT: the possible solution is to divide weekday to separate table:

### Table shop

id

### Table week_day

id
name
shop_id

### Table hours

id
time_from
time_to
week_day_id

In this case the example from wiki would work, but is there any solution to use instead of intermediate table just enums?

Comment: sorry but why can't you just map that relationship as bidirectional and add a @oneToMany  in shop entity?

Comment: I can, but it my shop will have several time interval, I'll loose all of them, except the db latest

Comment: uhmmm... no i think you don't unless i got that wrong...
You have a table shop and a table schedule and each schedule entry stand for day of the week and from/to interval... so if you have one shop to many schedule you get in shop a collection of schedule which represent multiple days and from/to intervals.
Am i wrong?

Comment: yes, but again, for example, if at MONDAY there is two interval 09:00-13:00 and 14:00-18:00, in collection I'll get map like this:
MONDAY -> 14:00-18:00
TUESDAY -> ....
The problem is that for every specific day, we can have multiple schedule intervals

Comment: JPA does not support this structure. You would need to work with a simple `List/Set<Schedule>` and transform to `Map<DayOfWeek, List<Schedule>>` in the in-memory model as hinted at in the deleted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used Java 8, then you could go with accessing the schedules on the shops with a simple inverse [OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) relationship in your `Shop` object

```
@OneToMany
private List<Schedule> scheduleList;
```

and then creating a method like

```
public Map<DayOfWeek, List<Schedule>> getScheduleListByDaysOfWeek() {
    return scheduleList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Schedule::getWeekday);
}
```

Comment: Answer undeleted because I finally had access to a compiler so I could fix my code that I wrote by heart.